# Using articles (the/a/an) when naming classes, functions and variables (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, naming-conventions

English isn't my native language and I have a question about naming in Swift.
Do I need to use articles (the/a/an) when naming any objects or functions?
Example:

```
func saveObject() or saveAnObject() or saveTheObject()
```

What is the best practice?

Comment: Naming practices is a hot topic and nothing is written in stone but it is widely accepted to ignore the, a and so on. For some guidance see [the api design guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/#naming) from swift.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first way, `saveObject()`, is the best practice. The other names are unnecessarily long.

Comment: Thx for your answer, If I understand correctly, I should not use articles when naming, although this is not correct from the point of view of the English language?

Comment: Exactly. In code, it's best to keep names short for simplicity. But in normal English, you'd use an article to describe the process of saving an object.